# Google Charts Horizontal BarChart calculate percentage

Tags: javascript, google-visualization

Is there a way to make the google BarChart to work like the PieChart?

The google´s PieChart sums all values you provided and give percentages. The BarChart does not do that when you work with horizontal columns, the length of the columns and the graph itself are based only on the values you provided and it does not label the horizontal axis with the percentage. 
Even though I format it with 'percentage' it only adds the % simbol to the current values.

Is there any way of doing that?

Comment: probably need to adjust the data you're providing instead, if you have some code, we can [help](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)...

Comment: I´m providing values that are not percentage, the same way I do with the pieChart, but pieChart automatically sums all values e calculates the percentage, the bar chart with horizontal bar doesn´t.

Comment: you can [group](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference#google_visualization_data_group) the data you provide to the chart

Comment: That seems nice, just wish this could be more 'automatic' like what the piechart does with the percentages. Good advice though, thanks!

Comment: anything else we can do to answer this question?

Comment: Well, I wish this could work automatically like the PieChart does but looks like it doesn´t, I had to do a little hack with javascript to suit my needs. I´m leaving this open for just a little while in case someone had the same need and found an answer.

Answer (score 3):

use the option `isStacked:'percent'`

https://jsfiddle.net/kzk07ocw/

Comment: That´s nice, the problem is that you are feeding the chart with 2 values 2010 and 2000, in my case it only feeds with one value, let´s say in your example I´m only giving the population of 2000.

Comment: It also works [**with 1 value**](https://jsfiddle.net/kzk07ocw/1/)(but I'm not sure what exactly  should be the desired result with 1 value)

Comment: I know, but the 100% value should be the sum of all values. For example I have 3 'bar' values, A=100, B=25 and C=25.
The bar 'A' should be at the middle of the chart while 'B' and 'C' should be at 1/4 of the chart.
In the example, all bars were at 100% because they are not doing this calculation that the PieChart does.

Comment: When A=100, B=25 and C=25 , then B and C would be 1/6 of the bar, and you would need a datatable with 1 row and 3 values: https://jsfiddle.net/kzk07ocw/3/

Comment: I see, but I would need this other bars in paralel and not stacked. I did a little hack with javascript to suit my need, but it´s sad that this percentage thing doesn´t work like the PieChart though. Thanks for the tips.